# Mouse gestures for Windows with "Rocker" support

Tags: windows, software-rec

I'm looking for a mouse gestures program for Windows (including XP). I've seen gMote and StrokeIt, both pretty good, but they're both missing one thing: support for Rocker Gestures.

If you don't know it, a Rocker gesture is just holding your right mouse button, then clicking your left (and vice versa). StrokeIt, at least, supports Rocker gestures in one direction, but not the other.

Anybody know of a good program that has support for Rocker gestures?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is one new freeware for Windows (XP, Vista, 7) called Just Gestures (http://justgestures.com) released just few days ago. It supports standard mouse gestures, Rocker gestures (but is called double button combination) and gestures performed as combination of pressing one mouse button and moving with mouse wheel (wheel button combination). You are not limited just to right and left mouse button, but you can create your own Rocker gestures as combination of any two mouse buttons. Also in Options is possible to deactivate the types of gestures you do not want to use.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this seems like a great new program and it does what I want. It has crashed on me a few times, but I'm hoping it will soon grow to be a great new gesture too.

Answer (score 0):

StrokeIt actually supports rocker gestures. See the `RBUTTON_DOWN`, `LBUTTON_DOWN`, and related gestures at the bottom of the list.